# hasFile function not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i am trying to upload a photo using Image Intervention Package 
i tried dd($request->hasFile('avator') ) and it return false
i returned "error" in my if statment  just to make sure that i have an error
**thanks in advance**

```
public function update_photo(Request $request){ 
    if($request->hasFile('avator') ){
        $avator = $request->file('avator');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $pic->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avator)->resize(300 , 300)->save(public_path('/uploads/avators' . $filename));
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avator = $filename ; 
        $user->save();
        echo "hello world !";
    }else {
        echo " Error"; // just to make sure that i have an error
    }
    return view("profile" , array("user" => Auth::user() ));

}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a slash(/) after avators in here '/uploads/avators'. try '/uploads/avators/'

Comment: check dd($request->file('avator')) . Did you get fileinfo? if not i think you missed sometinhg in your blade template.

Comment: @manian i was editing something before i push this :) even before the if stament dd($request->hasFile('avator')); return false

Comment: @AbdullahAlShakib it just return false as i said before . like what kind of errors can be in the blade template <img src= "/uploads/avators/{{Auth::user()->avator }}" alt="Picture" style="width:150px; height:150px ; float:left ;border-radius:50% ; margin-right:25px"  /><br>

Comment: @Markabham check the input field in your form. it should be like <input type="file" name="avator"/>

Answer (score 0):

*first edit this line of code*

```
$filename = time() . '.' . $avator->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

*add to this slash also*

```
Image::make($avator)->resize(300 , 300)->save(public_path('/uploads/avators/' . $filename));
```

*in your blade template make sure of spelling you are writing avator not avatar *

```
<input type="file" name="avator"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your blade put this in your form tag:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data
```

and in your controller:

```
use File;
```